# Apply over xts with multiple columns

Tags: r, apply, xts

I'm having a weird error which I can not understand. Let me explain the variables and their meaning:

```
ts <- a xts object
range.matrix <- matrix with two columns and n rows (only knows at execution time)
```

so, `range.matrix` contains ranges of dates. first column is the start of the range and second column is the end of it. The goal is to slice the ts time series by the ranges in range.matrix a get a list with all slices.

It fails with some ranges but not in others, and fails with 1 row matrices... The error message is:

> Error in array(ans, c(len.a%/%d2, d.ans), if (!is.null(names(dn.ans)) 
>   length of 'dimnames' 1 not equal to array extent

Check yourself with this toy example (`range.matrix` contains numbers which are cast as.Date)

```
    library(xts)
    ts <- xts(cbind('a'= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),'b' =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),'c'= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
            ,order.by = as.Date(as.Date('2017-01-01'):(as.Date('2017-01-01')+7)) )

    range.matrix <- matrix(c(16314,17286), ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE) # Fails. Range: "2014-09-01/2017-04-30"
    range.matrix <- matrix(c(16314,17236,16314,17286), ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE) # Fails. Range: "2014-09-01/2017-03-11" and "2014-09-01/2017-04-30"
    range.matrix <- matrix(c(16314,17236,17237,17286), ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE) # does not fail. "2014-09-01/2017-03-11" and "2017-03-12/2017-04-30"

    apply(range.matrix,
          1,
          function(r) {
          ts[paste0(as.Date(r[1]), '/', as.Date(r[2]))]
          })
```

Any clue? It has to do with `dimnames` but can not find the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead, and you won't have issues:

```
lapply(split(range.matrix, row(range.matrix)), function(x) {
  ts[paste0(as.Date(r[1]), '/', as.Date(r[2]))]})
```

Personally I would not use `apply` on `xts` objects in the way you want to do it (i'd do the above; `lapply` is much more natural).

`apply` is used on arrays, and an xts object is not just a matrix (array), but also supports a time index and other attributes that give xts its power.  You could use something like `coredata` on the xts object to just return the underlying matrix to the `apply` call, and then you won't get errors, but the results don't make much sense.

```
apply(range.matrix,
      1,
      function(r) {
        res <- ts[paste0(as.Date(r[1]), '/', as.Date(r[2]))]
        coredata(res)
      })
```

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I wanted "is it a bug?" but totally messed up